# Docusign OAuth 2.0 for Native C# Winform Application without using their dll

Tags: c#, winforms, docusignapi

I am having one C# winform application and using authentication for Docusign. How to get access token using OAuth 2.0 in winform application without referring their dlls, using only with HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - you'd need to pick a flow. ACG or JWT (https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/choose/)

Once you grant consent for your app - you would need to replicate what the DLLs do, i.e., call the `/oauth/token` endpoint with the appropriate payload as described in the documentation which would then return the access token. Then you can simply store the token (safely) and use it!

Comment: Ok thank you so much for your reply. But Consent is mandatory for all kind of  token ?

Comment: Yes, consent is mandatory. That's what signifies that an application is allowed to access DocuSign on your behalf